# How is Angular 2 library loaded?

Tags: angular

How is Angular 2 library loaded for a WebApp which is running on NodeJS?
Does it need ng-app if I am not using System.js? Or do we need to mention it specifically in index.html? (Doesn't look like that though)
How will it detect a custom component while rendering the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

it does not need a special tag/attribute like ng-app

The key is to call bootstrap function with your main App class/component as an argument

```
    import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
    import { App } from './app'; 
    import { SharedService } from './core/shared.service';  

    bootstrap(App, [SharedService] ) 
      .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success.`))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

If you want to render the app on server side, you could do something like this:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {ng2engine} from 'angular2-universal-preview';

// Angular 2
import {App} from './src/app';

let app = express();

// Express View
app.engine('.ng2.html', ng2engine);
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'ng2.html');


// static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { App });
});



app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listen on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: bootstrap is a part of angular 2 library. It loads the root component. When an index.html loads, how does it know whether it is angular or something else and works accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need System js for loading angular application in browser. As stated [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)  system js is

> Universal dynamic module loader - loads ES6 modules, AMD, CommonJS and global scripts in the browser and NodeJS.

These line of code :
`<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>`

in index.html is going to `import`aka load your app or application code.

Angular2 building blocks are components/modules which needs to be exported from one file in order to `import` into another. System.js loads these modules in browser. Then we have a component inside `index.html`for e.g 
`<my-app>` which gets replaced after Angular 2 bootstraps our application. 
you can read [official quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) for more info